# Why do my advanced key settings for input languages keep resetting?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, reset

I work in several different languages with my keyboard so I have always set up the advanced key settings to move quickly between input languages.  Recently my computer has started to reset the key sequences that I have applied.  I never used to have this problem, and I have not recognized any pattern to the resets.  Just some times I go to flip languages and the key sequence is no longer applied.  I then set it up again, and in coming days it is again turned off.  This is really annoying.  If anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: In my case Win10 resets Advanced Key Settings every time I lock/unlock my computer (e.g. with Win+L). I cannot believe Microsoft cannot fix such an annoying bug for so long time.

Comment: Just for history. This bug is not fixed yet - after some major Windows updates it breaks my workaround which have to be reapplied.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I managed to configure Advanced Key Settings in a way Win10 don't forget it between computer lock/unlock or reboots.

The trick is after "Change language bar hot keys" you should click on "Apply language settings to the welcome screen..." then click on button "Copy settings..." then check both "Welcome screen and system accounts" and "New user accounts" (I checked both just in case) and click OK. After this I've rebooted my computer and magic happened - my Ctrl+Shift+1 and Ctrl+Shift+2 hotkeys were working.

Try this workaround, hope it will help you.